# Angular / Firestore - Adding a formatted timestamp to a string field

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm writing a new document to Firestore. One of the fields must have some text, followed by the date, formatted like so `10/11/2020, 13:07`. What would be the simplest way to achieve this? I have an exceptionally convoluted way of achieving this with Moment.js in an old project. But I would like to see if there's a more elegant approach.

```
this.doc.set({
  title: "A New Title " + ,
  date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
})
```

In the above snippet, the title would need to be something like `title: "My New Title " + date"` so that the final result is something like: `My New Title -  10/11/2020, 13:07`

Comment: Apologies Frank. I was away for a few days. Updated. I'll respond to your post too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to merge a server-side timestamp with another value in a single write.

You will either have to:

1. Use a client-side date/time in the title.
2. Use an extra operation to read back the server-side data, and add it to the title.
3. Keep the date as a separate field (like you have now), and add it to the title whenever read read the document.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I appreciate the time. I just need to find an elegant way to achieve that.